# Move elements with xslt and renumber some id

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I need to move at the end of a section, all the p that have a certain class, I think the example may clarify:

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>MyPage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <section>
         <h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum</h1>
         <p class="text1">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sollicitudin<sup><a id="note-211-backlink" class="note-link" href="#note-211">211</a></sup>  tristique massa, quis luctus sem congue fermentum<sup><a id="note-212-backlink" class="note-link" href="#note-212">212</a></sup>. Maecenas venenatis enim ligula. Vestibulum rutrum laoreet rhoncus. Suspendisse vitae semper purus, et tincidunt ex. Aliquam a tortor placerat<sup><a id="note-213-backlink" class="note-link" href="#note-213">213</a></sup>, porta lectus ac, condimentum dolor. Etiam id urna aliquet, viverra urna id, efficitur dolor. Fusce consectetur, erat vitae sollicitudin malesuada, urna nisi imperdiet ligula, scelerisque porta sem orci non leo. Nulla vitae consequat enim<sup><a id="note-214-backlink" class="note-link" href="#note-214">214</a></sup>. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam a iaculis metus.
         </p>
         <div class="inline-notes">
            <p class="note"><a id="note-211" class="note-anchor" href="#note-211-backlink">211</a> Cras id nibh et lacus pulvinar hendrerit eget vel massa.
            </p>
            <p class="note"><a id="note-212" class="note-anchor" href="#note-212-backlink">212</a> Fusce quis metus ac nisl lacinia porta.
            </p>
            <p class="note"><a id="note-213" class="note-anchor" href="#note-213-backlink">213</a> Phasellus vestibulum volutpat ipsum.
            </p>
            <p class="note"><a id="note-214" class="note-anchor" href="#note-214-backlink">214</a> Vestibulum eu libero non lorem vulputate scelerisque.
            </p>
         </div>
         <p class="text2">Nullam ipsum enim, laoreet quis neque suscipit<sup><a id="note-215-backlink" class="note-link" href="#note-215">215</a></sup>, ornare sodales orci. Curabitur fringilla ornare ullamcorper. Pellentesque eu sem leo<sup><a id="note-216-backlink" class="note-link" href="#note-216">216</a></sup>. Cras eu consectetur mi, ac sagittis diam. Nunc at odio ac arcu mollis pharetra.
         </p>
         <div class="inline-notes">
            <p class="note"><a id="note-215" class="note-anchor" href="#note-215-backlink">215</a> Praesent bibendum lacus ac dolor eleifend porta.
            </p>
            <p class="note"><a id="note-216" class="note-anchor" href="#note-216-backlink">216</a> Phasellus vestibulum volutpat ipsum.
            </p>
         </div>
      </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

Desired result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>MyPage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <section>
         <h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum</h1>
         <p class="text1">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sollicitudin<sup><a id="note-1-backlink" class="note-link" href="#note-1">1</a></sup>  tristique massa, quis luctus sem congue fermentum<sup><a id="note-2-backlink" class="note-link" href="#note-2">2</a></sup>. Maecenas venenatis enim ligula. Vestibulum rutrum laoreet rhoncus. Suspendisse vitae semper purus, et tincidunt ex. Aliquam a tortor placerat<sup><a id="note-3-backlink" class="note-link" href="#note-3">3</a></sup>, porta lectus ac, condimentum dolor. Etiam id urna aliquet, viverra urna id, efficitur dolor. Fusce consectetur, erat vitae sollicitudin malesuada, urna nisi imperdiet ligula, scelerisque porta sem orci non leo. Nulla vitae consequat enim<sup><a id="note-4-backlink" class="note-link" href="#note-4">4</a></sup>. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam a iaculis metus.
         </p>
         <p class="text2">Nullam ipsum enim, laoreet quis neque suscipit<sup><a id="note-5-backlink" class="note-link" href="#note-5">5</a></sup>, ornare sodales orci. Curabitur fringilla ornare ullamcorper. Pellentesque eu sem leo<sup><a id="note-6-backlink" class="note-link" href="#note-6">6</a></sup>. Cras eu consectetur mi, ac sagittis diam. Nunc at odio ac arcu mollis pharetra.
         </p>
         <div class="note-container">
            <p class="note"><a id="note-1" class="note-anchor" href="#note-1-backlink">1</a> Cras id nibh et lacus pulvinar hendrerit eget vel massa.
            </p>
            <p class="note"><a id="note-2" class="note-anchor" href="#note-2-backlink">2</a> Fusce quis metus ac nisl lacinia porta.
            </p>
            <p class="note"><a id="note-3" class="note-anchor" href="#note-3-backlink">3</a> Phasellus vestibulum volutpat ipsum.
            </p>
            <p class="note"><a id="note-4" class="note-anchor" href="#note-4-backlink">4</a> Vestibulum eu libero non lorem vulputate scelerisque.
            </p>
            <p class="note"><a id="note-5" class="note-anchor" href="#note-5-backlink">5</a> Praesent bibendum lacus ac dolor eleifend porta.
            </p>
            <p class="note"><a id="note-6" class="note-anchor" href="#note-6-backlink">6</a> Phasellus vestibulum volutpat ipsum.
            </p>
         </div>
      </section>
```

This is my xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:gb="http://www.digitaltypes.it"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs h gb #default"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="h:section">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <div class="note_container">
         </div>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[@class='note']"/>
    <xsl:template match="//div[@class='note_container']">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="//p[contains(@class,'note')]"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have tried several possibilities, but no one worked for me. I can't understand how to move the various p of class notes, in the div note-container that I can create. Now it's not very important, to renumber the id, I want to understand how to move this tag.

Thank you at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to Michaels answer, but handles `note-link`'s too.

**XML Input**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>MyPage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum</h1>
            <p class="text1">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sollicitudin<sup><a id="note-211-backlink" class="note-link" href="#note-211">211</a></sup>  tristique massa, quis luctus sem congue fermentum<sup><a id="note-212-backlink" class="note-link" href="#note-212">212</a></sup>. Maecenas venenatis enim ligula. Vestibulum rutrum laoreet rhoncus. Suspendisse vitae semper purus, et tincidunt ex. Aliquam a tortor placerat<sup><a id="note-213-backlink" class="note-link" href="#note-213">213</a></sup>, porta lectus ac, condimentum dolor. Etiam id urna aliquet, viverra urna id, efficitur dolor. Fusce consectetur, erat vitae sollicitudin malesuada, urna nisi imperdiet ligula, scelerisque porta sem orci non leo. Nulla vitae consequat enim<sup><a id="note-214-backlink" class="note-link" href="#note-214">214</a></sup>. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam a iaculis metus.
            </p>
            <div class="inline-notes">
                <p class="note"><a id="note-211" class="note-anchor" href="#note-211-backlink">211</a> Cras id nibh et lacus pulvinar hendrerit eget vel massa.
                </p>
                <p class="note"><a id="note-212" class="note-anchor" href="#note-212-backlink">212</a> Fusce quis metus ac nisl lacinia porta.
                </p>
                <p class="note"><a id="note-213" class="note-anchor" href="#note-213-backlink">213</a> Phasellus vestibulum volutpat ipsum.
                </p>
                <p class="note"><a id="note-214" class="note-anchor" href="#note-214-backlink">214</a> Vestibulum eu libero non lorem vulputate scelerisque.
                </p>
            </div>
            <p class="text2">Nullam ipsum enim, laoreet quis neque suscipit<sup><a id="note-215-backlink" class="note-link" href="#note-215">215</a></sup>, ornare sodales orci. Curabitur fringilla ornare ullamcorper. Pellentesque eu sem leo<sup><a id="note-216-backlink" class="note-link" href="#note-216">216</a></sup>. Cras eu consectetur mi, ac sagittis diam. Nunc at odio ac arcu mollis pharetra.
            </p>
            <div class="inline-notes">
                <p class="note"><a id="note-215" class="note-anchor" href="#note-215-backlink">215</a> Praesent bibendum lacus ac dolor eleifend porta.
                </p>
                <p class="note"><a id="note-216" class="note-anchor" href="#note-216-backlink">216</a> Phasellus vestibulum volutpat ipsum.
                </p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node() except div[tokenize(@class,'\s')='inline-notes']"/>
      <div class="note-container">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="div[tokenize(@class,'\s')='inline-notes']/*"/>
      </div>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a[tokenize(@class,'\s')='note-anchor']">
    <xsl:variable name="noteNbr">
      <xsl:number count="a[tokenize(@class,'\s')='note-anchor']" level="any"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <a id="{concat('note-',$noteNbr)}" href="{concat('#note-',$noteNbr,'-backlink')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except (@href,@id),$noteNbr"/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a[tokenize(@class,'\s')='note-link']">
    <xsl:variable name="noteNbr" select="index-of(//a[tokenize(@class,'\s')='note-anchor']/@id,substring-after(@href,'#'))"/>
    <a id="{concat('note-',$noteNbr,'-backlink')}" href="{concat('#note-',$noteNbr)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except (@id,@href)"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$noteNbr"/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <title>MyPage</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <section>
         <h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum</h1>
         <p class="text1">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sollicitudin<sup>
               <a id="note-1-backlink" href="#note-1" class="note-link">1</a>
            </sup>  tristique massa, quis luctus sem congue fermentum<sup>
               <a id="note-2-backlink" href="#note-2" class="note-link">2</a>
            </sup>. Maecenas venenatis enim ligula. Vestibulum rutrum laoreet rhoncus. Suspendisse vitae semper purus, et tincidunt ex. Aliquam a tortor placerat<sup>
               <a id="note-3-backlink" href="#note-3" class="note-link">3</a>
            </sup>, porta lectus ac, condimentum dolor. Etiam id urna aliquet, viverra urna id, efficitur dolor. Fusce consectetur, erat vitae sollicitudin malesuada, urna nisi imperdiet ligula, scelerisque porta sem orci non leo. Nulla vitae consequat enim<sup>
               <a id="note-4-backlink" href="#note-4" class="note-link">4</a>
            </sup>. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam a iaculis metus.
            </p>
         <p class="text2">Nullam ipsum enim, laoreet quis neque suscipit<sup>
               <a id="note-5-backlink" href="#note-5" class="note-link">5</a>
            </sup>, ornare sodales orci. Curabitur fringilla ornare ullamcorper. Pellentesque eu sem leo<sup>
               <a id="note-6-backlink" href="#note-6" class="note-link">6</a>
            </sup>. Cras eu consectetur mi, ac sagittis diam. Nunc at odio ac arcu mollis pharetra.
            </p>
         <div class="note-container">
            <p class="note">
               <a id="note-1" href="#note-1-backlink" class="note-anchor">1</a> Cras id nibh et lacus pulvinar hendrerit eget vel massa.
                </p>
            <p class="note">
               <a id="note-2" href="#note-2-backlink" class="note-anchor">2</a> Fusce quis metus ac nisl lacinia porta.
                </p>
            <p class="note">
               <a id="note-3" href="#note-3-backlink" class="note-anchor">3</a> Phasellus vestibulum volutpat ipsum.
                </p>
            <p class="note">
               <a id="note-4" href="#note-4-backlink" class="note-anchor">4</a> Vestibulum eu libero non lorem vulputate scelerisque.
                </p>
            <p class="note">
               <a id="note-5" href="#note-5-backlink" class="note-anchor">5</a> Praesent bibendum lacus ac dolor eleifend porta.
                </p>
            <p class="note">
               <a id="note-6" href="#note-6-backlink" class="note-anchor">6</a> Phasellus vestibulum volutpat ipsum.
                </p>
         </div>
      </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

Note: I used `tokenize(@class,'\s')` just in case you had a class attribute with more than one value.

---

Edit for OP's comment `So i have a question there is a way, via xslt, to apply the xslt only when exist the <div class="inline-notes">??`:

You could add another template that overrides the root element when that `div` doesn't exist:

```
<xsl:template match="/*[not(//div[tokenize(@class,'\s')='inline-notes'])]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, you could wrap the note-container `div` in an `xsl:if`:

```
<xsl:template match="section">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node() except div[tokenize(@class,'\s')='inline-notes']"/>
    <xsl:if test="div[tokenize(@class,'\s')='inline-notes']">
      <div class="note-container">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="div[tokenize(@class,'\s')='inline-notes']/*"/>
      </div>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Oh, my. I did not realize these notes were referenced in the text (I wish people would *explain* their requirements, instead of just dumping an example on us). Well, here's the rub: at least in theory, a note could be referenced twice (or more). Also, there's no guarantee - at last in theory - that the references appear in the same order as the notes they reference. This would mean that the references cannot be renumbered independently of the notes.

Comment: Ok this work very fine for me @michael i have another xslt that create the link, and i am sure that a not is referenced only one time whit his sup. And sorry if i don't explain well my requirements, but my english is not good...

Comment: So i have a question there is a way, via xslt, to apply the xslt only when exist the <div class="inline-notes">??

Comment: @michael.hor257k - The way I'm getting the new note number, the order of the references doesn't matter. Multiple references don't matter either. Here's an example where I switch the order of the references for 211 and 212 and I also add an additional reference to 211. http://xsltransform.net/ej9EGco/1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
exclude-result-prefixes="h">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h:section">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node() except h:div[@class='inline-notes']"/>
        <div class="note_container">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="h:div[@class='inline-notes']/h:p[@class='note']"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h:p[@class='note']">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <a id="note-{$i}" class="note-anchor" href="#note-{$i}-backlink">
            <xsl:value-of select="$i"/>
        </a> 
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of the `h:` prefix as well as the default namespace declaration.